# changing a url for web service that uses SOAP

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

For a school project we had to make a website and an ipod app that interacts with a web service. Both the website and web service are in the same server that the school provided. Everything was working perfectly till my school changed up the server so now we need to add the port to the url:

before: xxx.com/group5Website

after:  xxx.com:81/group5Website

Now whenever we try to invoke the web service it sends us to the old page and says "The resource cannot be found." because its still directing us to the old site (xxx.com/group5Website/webService/AppServicev1.asmx/getLot)

The problem is we don't have access to the actual server, just the files stored on your group5Website, is there anyway to fix this?

It is a asp.net based website, thanks and hope someone knows what to do cause I really don't want to fail haha

Comment: How did you initialize the URL in your project?

Comment: If worst comes to worst, do a Search and Replace for the entire solution and replace any references to the URL.

Comment: not too sure what you mean by initialize the url

but for the search and replace I tried what this site said to replace it but it didn't seem to work:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/11/16/493496.aspx

Comment: unless you mean the web service then its done like this:

`[WebService(Namespace = "http://xxx.com:81/group5Website/webService/AppServicev1.asmx")]`

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the old web reference and add the new web reference.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

> In Solution Explorer, right-click the Web reference and then click Delete.
>
> All the reference information is removed from the project and from local storage.

Comment: when I try to use  `http://xxx.com:81/group5Website/webService/AppServicev1.asmx` as a reference it shows up fine, then I click add reference I get a pop up saying: 
  

`Unablt to download following files from .  
http://xxx.com:81/group5Website/webService/AppServicev1.asmx?wsdl  
Do you want to skip these files and continue?`

Comment: sorry it says:  
`Unablt to download following files from . http://xxx.com/group5Website/webService/AppServicev1.asmx?wsdl Do you want to skip these files and continue?`